# How to return an custom output with status code in Zapier rest hook perform?

Tags: hook, zapier, zapier-cli

I am using Zapier web builder to create a Zapier APP. I have rest hooks, when I subscribing for a hook API sends a verification challenge code, this comes in the `perform`

Here is the content that I am receiving in query string :

```
hub.mode=subscribe&hub.challenge=97890257&hub.verify_token=12345
```

Zapier returning below back to api:

`{"id": "732a8cfc-1dcc-4b54-9a55-7d21e0858ad6", "request_id": "5feb0139-a858-4fbc-b32d-47e13ff472a0", "attempt": "5feb0139-a858-4fbc-b32d-47e13ff472a0", "status": "success"}`

I want to modify the return response and status code.

Please advise?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of Jan 2021, Zapier doesn't support modifying the default webhook response (`{id: ..., attempt: ..., etc}`). Unfortunately, this means it can't be used for integrating with webhook services that require a specific challenge response.

We're looking into this functionality, but have no timetable for if/when it'll be available.

Comment: ```Lead Ads By facebook``` also require similer integration, and this is already working on zapier, so Is there any alternbative solution that I can use to achieve this?

Comment: FBLA is a special internal case that leverages code not available to external developers. There's not a workaround at this time (but we hope there will be in the future!)